# Row Index error in my delete button gridview

Tags: c#

This code that im showing is totally working fine in cell click event. But i've inserted some buttons in the gridview and one of that is the "delete" button. While I was transferring the code from the cell click event to the button delete, I encounter this error. Can somebody please tell me what do I need to change in the code so that the delete function will be fix?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(maincon);
            string rfidno = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rfidno"].FormattedValue.ToString();

            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this information?", "Delete function triggered", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from tbl_registerStudent where rfidno = '" + rfidno + "'", sqlcon);
                    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    MessageBox.Show("" + rfidno);
                    MessageBox.Show("Delete Successfull");
                    sqlcon.Close();
                    bindGrid();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                CreateID objs = new CreateID();
                if (objs == null)
                {
                    objs.Parent = this;
                }
                objs.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Which line in the code throws the error?

Comment: `string rfidno = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["rfidno"].FormattedValue.ToString();` and check first the `CurrentRow`, if its null or `IsNewRow` then you should `return;`.

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya this is the line that throws the error. 

string rfidno = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["rfidno"].FormattedValue.ToString();

Comment: Hi @dr.null.. Thanks the problem is now solved. May I ask where should I add the return;? My datagridview cell click event is set to null;

Comment: Should be the first line in the `button3` click event shown above. `if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow == null || dataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow) return;` You can omit the `IsNewRow` check if the `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows` is false.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use e.RowIndex in a buttonclick event handler because the `e` that is passed in doesn't have that property.

You should handle this in the same way you previously did; attach a handler to the CellContentClick of the datagridview and carry out this code if the column that is clicked is the button column I.e. don't do this:

> While I was transferring the code from the cell click event

Just make the cell click event test "if the column that was clicked is the button column then..."